# Three-Dimensional Routing

Tags: qgis, altitude, 3d-map

I have created a route by hand using the Tracing Tool available in QGIS, placing the waypoint on top of an Open Street Map layer. I wanted to export all the coordinates to another program, so I saved them in a CSV file. The problem is that I can only see the latitudes and longitudes, but not the altitudes associated to each pair of latitude-longitude point. I think that my problem is that OSM doesn't work with the z-axis.

I want to create a track specifying only the latitude and longitude of each waypoint in a way that the program automatically tells the altitude of the road/street at each waypoint. Someone knows how could I do it?

Comment: Can you clarify a few things?

What tool were you using to create your track?

Are you having trouble with creating 3D geometries or with exporting them?

Comment: Sure. I created a new shapefile layer (type:line) and in the toggle editing mode I selected the icons "add feature" and "enable tracing". Regarding to your second question, I am having trouble exporting them but I think that the reason is that the layer I have created is in 2D. I don't know at what point of the process I must specify that I want to work in 3D...

Comment: Not for qgis ... but do you mean something like this? https://graphhopper.com/maps/?point=47.916342%2C8.151855&point=46.570191%2C11.181335&layer=TF%20Outdoors See bottom right corner and mouse over it. The component we use is called leaflet elevation plugin: https://github.com/MrMufflon/Leaflet.Elevation You could probably bridge qgis with this if I'm not wrong